# How implement a button clear in a RadDatePicker

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, raddatepicker

I found an example of a "clear" button (to remove input content) for a text input here: 
http://jsbin.com/bebug/5/edit?html,css,js,output

I have used it in an `ASPTextBox` in Microsoft ASP.Net, but it is possible to implement in Telerik's `RadDatePicker`?

If yes, an example of how to do so would be helpful.

[image]

Comment: Please include a code example of what you have tried.  Preferably in how you have tried to make this work in a RadDatePicker.

Comment: I have the same code that is in the link, did not work

Comment: The code that is in the link isn't for a RadDatePicker.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: See the example picture  I added in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSS COde is the same, and JQUERY is this:

https://github.com/keir/jquery-ui/commit/25e55ff73df768360a2260534a4afa6e03f04fb